# timer on thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer

Can i create successfully a timer clock on a thread? i'm creating one but it doesn't seem to work that well. My app is a multi-thread app that has to start a timer on a thread when ever a certain event happens. The timer is placed in every client connection. The clock doesn't work until i close my winform(i don't know why) . Is there anything in particular that i should know about timers in threads ?

Here is my timer code :

```
timer1.Interval = 1000;
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Start();
```

Comment: `timer1.Enabled` does the same as `timer1.Start()`, so you only need one of them. Try configuring the timer somewhere outside the thread and use `this.Invoke` to call `timer1.Start()`.

Comment: One interesting detail that is left out here is *where, when and how the timer is created*. The code sample only shows how it is started.

Comment: @Dittmar : i need a timer for every client connection that i accept so i must declare it ( most likely ) in the class that defines my connection. @ fredrik i declare the timer for every connection when i create the class

Comment: *when i create the object that contains my connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try to use `System.Threading.Timer`, which is basically a timer that's in a separate thread. You might also consider using a `WaitHandle` that's never fired and then using `WaitOne(1000, false)` to wait for a second.

Comment: Well, I actually don't really know :-) I'd try the `System.Threading.Timer`, as it does not depend on Windows Forms like the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` - you never know... As you create the timer in the thread's code anyway, there's not much overhead if you switch classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void EnableTimer()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new Action(EnableTimer));
            else
                this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
```